# Keras RNN How to predict more than data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I get time series data from 08/02/2014 to now date (08/02/2019). In this code RNN can predict and compare result with test set. I want to predict more than test set such as predict to date 15/02/2019 How to use Keras predict more than data set ?

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('ibm',
                          start=datetime.datetime(2014, 02, 08),
                          end=pd.datetime.now().date())

train = df.loc[:datetime.datetime(2019, 1,14), ['Close']]
test = df.loc[datetime.datetime(2019, 1,15):, ['Close']]

sc = MinMaxScaler()
train_sc = sc.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = sc.transform(test)

X_train = train_sc[:-1]
y_train = train_sc[1:]

X_test = test_sc[:-1]
y_test = test_sc[1:]

K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=2)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: look into time series forcasting

Comment: You can use the predicted value as input for the future forecast.